# 3D visualization of complex geometries in a GUI

Tags: opengl, pygtk, glade, vtk, opencascade

I would like to develop a small cross-platform for  (structured) mesh  generation software (similar to [Gmesh](http://goo.gl/UHjft)) and possibly 3D pre/post processing (like [Salome](http://goo.gl/MO7Cf)).
In order to make things easier I'd like to use already made libraries, to better focus on the development of what I need.
I need 
1. geometrical modelling capabilities 
2. GUI
3. 3D visualization. 
I have been looking around but the whole workflow results a bit blurry. 
I think **pyGTK** and **GLADE** are good choices for me ( because of the community and the very open license with respect to **pyQt**).
 
The modelling part could be handled by **Open Cascade** ( preferably **pythonOCC**) but for the visulization in a pyGTK widget I don't know what to do. 
I was thinking to use **openGL** (**PyGtkGLExt**) but I understood that OpenGL is too low-level. 
 **FreeCAD** (http://goo.gl/V4FCW) uses **Coin3D** (I could use **pyvy** maybe) for this reason but a software like **Gmesh** uses directly **OpenGL**. 
On top of that I saw that for scientific visualization, **VTK** would be probably better, but I don't understand  whether  it is based on OpenGL or not. In my opinion OpenGL is nice because it is supported by graphic card drivers making the whole software faster.

I should be able to render geometries built by pythonOCC into a pyGTK widget but what kind of libraries would be better to use? OpenGL alone (maybe to complex to program?)
Coin3D (or similar) to speed up the use of OpenGL? 
VTK alone? VTK in combination with OpenGL? 
Other combination and/or libraries? 
Have you experience in this kind of software? 
Do you have suggestion about it? Do you know tutorials where the combined used of these libraries is explained?